# Deploying a custom HAPI FHIR server using docker compose

Tags: java, docker, maven, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I cloned the [hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter) and modified the code to meet my requirements then did as they said in the [README](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter#deploy-with-docker-compose) file:

```
mvn clean install
docker-compose up -d --build
```

It did deploy the server **but** with a new fresh HAPI server, not the one I modified and built.

How can I use docker compose to deploy my build not the version he gets from the docker repo?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to update the DockerFile to use your modified code, from your fork, rather than from the original repository:

```
ARG HAPI_FHIR_STARTER_URL=https://github.com/path/to/your/repo
ARG HAPI_FHIR_STARTER_BRANCH=your_branch
```

Alternatively, perhaps have a look if this commit resolved the issue for you? https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir-jpaserver-starter/commit/213bda7cfcc2d5f6f150b8781093b315a17a43c2